# Why adding spread operator make code returns empty array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Now, i am creating a book tracking app using react and redux, i need to fetch data asynchronously, and now i have 3 versions of code
two of them return the expected result but not the third

**The first one:**

```
import { FETCH_BOOKS } from '../actions/Types.js';

import * as BooksAPI from '../BooksAPI'

export const bookReducer = (state = [], action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_BOOKS:
         console.log (BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => books))

      default: 
         return state;
 }
}
//Promise {<pending>}
//this returns a promise in a pending state that is resolved to array of objects(expected)
```

**The second one:**

```
import { FETCH_BOOKS } from '../actions/Types.js';

import * as BooksAPI from '../BooksAPI'

export const bookReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
     case FETCH_BOOKS:
        console.log ([BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => books)])

     default: 
        return state;
 }
}
//[promise]
//this returns an array of a promise that is resolved to array of another array of books objects(expected)
```

**The third one:**

```
import { FETCH_BOOKS } from '../actions/Types.js';

import * as BooksAPI from '../BooksAPI'

export const bookReducer = (state = [], action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_BOOKS:
         console.log ([...BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => books)])

      default: 
         return state;
 }
}
//[]
//this returns an empty array, no promise
//expected spreading items of the returned array of objects not empty array!!
```

**So what is wrong here??**

Comment: Actually your third snippet will not even work because a Promise is not iterable.

Comment: That is right!!
is there a way to achieve that

 @Derek 朕會功夫

Comment: @SaherElgendy You're doing a thing that doesn't make sense from JS perspective, and no, there's no way to achieve that. There wouldn't be a bunch of middlewares like the answer lists if this would be possible with Redux itself. Consider using redux-promise if you want to address specifically promises.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't directly an answer to your question, but i wanted to point out that reducers need to be synchronous. If you want to do async stuff with redux you'll need to include an async middleware. Some popular options are:

- [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) (based around promises)
- [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) (based around generators)
- [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) (based around observables)